# Show All Posts in Theme Options

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show all custom posts in Theme options, I am using Theme Options Framework plugin. Here is the code where you can grab all pages but I don't know how to fetch all posts in checkbox so user can select which custom posts show on homepage.

```
// Pull all the pages into an array
$options_pages = array();
$options_pages_obj = get_pages( 'sort_column=post_parent,menu_order' );
$options_pages[''] = 'Select a page:';
foreach ($options_pages_obj as $page) {
    $options_pages[$page->ID] = $page->post_title;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for select it is:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$posts = get_posts( $args );
if($posts) {
 echo "<select>";
  foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    echo "<option value="$post->ID">";
     echo $post->post_title;
    echo "</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
  wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
?>
```

For checkbox it is:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$posts = get_posts( $args );
if($posts) {

  foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    echo "<div>";
     echo "<label>".$post->post_title."</label>";
     echo "<input name='posts[]' value='".$post->ID."' type='checkbox' />";
    echo "</div>";
  }
  wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its working but showing on Select box :(. I want to show checkboxes

Comment: Thanks for your reply.<code>$options[] = array(
  'name' => __('Select a Page', 'options_framework_theme'),
  'desc' => __('Passed an pages with ID and post_title', 'options_framework_theme'),
  'id' => 'example_select_pages',
  'type' => 'select',
  'options' => $options_pages);
</code>

Comment: I am using Theme option framework how can i put this code in the theme options

Comment: look for this : https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-wordpress-theme-settings-page-with-the-settings-api/